# pandas column calculated using function including dict lookup, 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mutable

I am aware there are tons of questions similar to mine, but I could not find the solution to my question in the last 30 Minutes of looking through dozens of threads.

I have a dataframe with hundereds of columns and rows, and use most columns within a function to return a value thats supposed to be added to an additional column.

The problem can be broken down to the following.

```
lookup = {"foo": 1, "bar": 0}

def lookuptable(input_string, input_factor):
    return lookup[input_string] * input_factor

mydata = pd.DataFrame([["foo", 4], ["bar",3]], columns = ["string","faktor"])
mydata["looked up value"] = lookuptable(mydata["string"], mydata["faktor"])
```

But this returns:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Is there a way to avoid this problem without, restructuring the function itself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lookup = {"foo": 1, "bar": 0}

def lookuptable(data):
    return lookup[data["string"]] * data["faktor"]

mydata = pd.DataFrame([["foo", 4], ["bar",3]], columns = ["string","faktor"])
mydata["looked up value"] = mydata.apply(lookuptable, axis=1)

print(mydata)

    string  faktor  looked up value
0   foo        4        4
1   bar        3        0
```

Comment: Thank you. This appears to be very similar to what Andreas was proposing.

Answer (score 2):

Besides of using `.apply()`, you can use list comprehension with `.iterrows()`

```
mydata["looked up value"] = [lookuptable(row[1]["string"], row[1]["faktor"]) for row in mydata.iterrows()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functions accepts 2 parameters, a string and a integer.
But you provide 2 pandas series to the function instead. You can iterate through the dataframe however and provide the function with the parameters (row-wise) by using `.apply()`.

```
mydata["looked up value"] = mydata\
.apply(lambda row: lookuptable(row["string"], row["faktor"]), axis=1)
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I no have many other bugs so I'll accept your answer once my code is bug free.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without function -

```
import pandas as pd
lookup = {"foo": 1, "bar": 0}
mydata = pd.DataFrame([["foo", 4], ["bar",3]], columns = ["string","factor"])
mydata["looked up value"] = mydata['string'].map(lookup) * mydata['factor']
```

Comment: I know. But as discribed. The original function contains more than 100 values and is used in many different locations throughout my program

Comment: So, replace the function call with assignment everywhere. I'm not sure but this may work faster than apply.